# How to replace below function?

Tags: c, function, memcpy

Below is given explanation for PUTADDR function what exactly it does.

```
/** This wrapper function to memcpy will put the actual address value
* pointed by pSrc to destination pointer.
* ex. LA    R1,FIDTBLEN(,R1)
*     L     R15,4(,R1)
*     --> MOVE R1-DATA(5:4) TO R15-PTR
*         Note that R1-DATA(5:4) is verified to hold an address
* @param [OUT pDest holds the address of destination pointer
* @param [IN pSrc Memory region that holds the pointer address value
*            to be copied
* @return void/none

static void PUTADDR(void **pDest, const void *pSrc)
{
   /*ACNFIX zOS COMPATIBILITY START*/
    #ifdef DEBUG
    /*START Code Optimization*/
    if (NULL == pDest || NULL == pSrc)
    {
        ABENDRTN(C_USERABEND_CODE, C_USERABEND_MSG);
    }
    /*END Code Optimization*/
    #endif
   /*ACNFIX zOS COMPATIBILITY END*/
    memcpy(pDest, pSrc, sizeof(void *));
}
```

*****How Can we rewrite the following code without using PUTADDR*****

```
PUTADDR((void**)&r8_ptr_g, r8_ptr_g+2);
```

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages. C and C++ are two very different languages, only that the one you're actually programming in.

Comment: please pick one language. Also the question is unclear. If calling the function is not allowed, what is allowed? Is renaming the function ok? Is copying the body of the function and replace the call with it ok? Whats the actual aim?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `(void**)&r8` is likely a bug - you can't cast a pointer to pointer to object to a pointer to pointer to void.

Comment: And `memcpy(pDest, pSrc, sizeof(void *));` doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `*pDest`?

Comment: @0___________ Sure, but the code is changing the argument, not the pointer that `pDest` points to.

Comment: Please change the question title to a more significant one so other users may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> How Can we rewrite the following code without using PUTADDR
>
> ```
> PUTADDR((void**)&r8_ptr_g, r8_ptr_g+2);
> ```

```c
memcpy(&r8_ptr_g, r8_ptr_g+2, sizeof(&r8_ptr_g));
```

or more simple

```c
r8_ptr_g = r8_ptr_g + 2;
```

Comment: @thebusybee `r8_ptr_g += 2` is not simpler, it is exactly the same - it is a different notation

Comment: It is simpler, because you see at a glance that a single variable is modified. The other statement needs mental work to see that both variable names are the same. -- Simplicity is more to the reader, not the compiler.